# Can a green card holder continue to legally maintain and use an existing NRE account?

Tags: united-states, india, bank-account, non-resident

I am an Indian citizen in US and used to have non immigrant visa and recently got green card. I already have a NRE account. Can a green card holder continue to legally maintain and use an existing NRE account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can a green card holder continue to legally maintain and use an existing NRE account?

**TL: DNR version:** Yes.

Your immigration status in the US has very little to do with NRE accounts, and you can continue to hold the same NRE account(s) after getting your green card as you held previously. You don't even need to inform your bank that you now have a green card in the US. Now, if and when you acquire US citizenship, you *must* tell the bank (they may ask for a fresh KYC or a reKYC) because you will have changed legal status from an NRI (NonResident Indian) to a PIO (Person of Indian Origin) and there are things that you cannot do as a PIO that you were entitled to do as an NRI.

Comment: Thanks Dilip for a detailed reply